# How to replace pandas dataframe column names with another list or dictionary matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I need to replace column names of a pandas DataFrame having names like 'real_tag' and rename them like 'Descripcion'

```
list = [{'real_tag': 'FA0:4AIS0007', 'Descripcion': 'velocidad burbujas celda 7'}, {'real_tag': 'FA0:4FIC0116_PVLOLM', 'Descripcion': 'LIMITE BAJO FLUJO AIRE CELDA 2 FLOT. A0'}]
```

Is there any way I can achieve this? Names need to match...

Comment: So a column named `'FA0:4AIS0007'` should become `'velocidad burbujas celda 7'`?

Comment: exactly.... matching names

Comment: `df.rename(columns={item['real_tag']:item['Descripcion'] for item in list}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dictionary mapping old to new names, then use `DataFrame.rename`.

Setup

```
>>> lst = [{'real_tag': 'FA0:4AIS0007', 'Descripcion': 'velocidad burbujas celda 7'}, {'real_tag': 'FA0:4FIC0116_PVLOLM', 'Descripcion': 'LIMITE BAJO FLUJO AIRE CELDA 2 FLOT. A0'}]                                                   
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['FA0:4AIS0007', 'FA0:4FIC0116_PVLOLM', 'X'])                                                                                                                                               
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   FA0:4AIS0007  FA0:4FIC0116_PVLOLM  X
0             1                    2  3
```

Solution

```
>>> mapping = {d['real_tag']:d['Descripcion'] for d in lst} 
>>> df.rename(mapping, axis='columns')                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   velocidad burbujas celda 7  LIMITE BAJO FLUJO AIRE CELDA 2 FLOT. A0  X
0                           1                                        2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename` method of dataframe and pass dictionary (key as old name, value as new name) to the columns argument.

given a dataframe `df` and your list of columns `list`:

```py
df.rename(columns={item['real_tag']:item['Descripcion'] for item in list}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set a data frame, you can edit its `columns` attribute to change the names. Be careful though, you need to keep the column order constant:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]],    columns=['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'])
df.columns = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma']
```